# How do I perform calculations with sublists in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get 4 average numbers from the 4 sublists from my main list. I'm getting the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list. Can someone explain my what that means in this context?

```
studentgrades = [ [95, 92, 86],[66, 75, 54],[89, 72, 100],[34, 0, 0] ]

antw = []
for student in studentgrades:
     average = sum(studentgrades[student]) / len(studentgrades[student])
     antw.append(average)


print(antw)
```

Comment: You just need to replace your line where you compute average with `average = sum(student) / len(student)`. Rest of your code is **perfectly** fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you went wrong was going a little to far with this, your original function will work fine if you take the extra elements you added off. In your loop `students` is representing already each individual element, so there is no need to call it again as `studentgrades[student]`

```
antw = []
for student in studentgrades:
     average = sum(student) / len(student)
     antw.append(average)
```

This can be done using *list comprehension* or a single loop appending to a list

```
studentgrades = [ [95, 92, 86],[66, 75, 54],[89, 72, 100],[34, 0, 0] ]
l = [round(sum(i)/len(i), 2) for i in studentgrades]
# [91.0, 65.0, 87.0, 11.33]
```

Expanded

```
l = []
for i in studentgrades:
    total = sum(i)
    grades = len(i)
    average = total/grades
    l.append(round(average, 2))
```

Another option would be `map` that allows us to apply the function to all the list elements

```
l = list(map(lambda x: round(sum(x)/len(x), 2), studentgrades))
```

Comment: Before providing an alternate solution to the OP who seems to be a beginner, it's a good practice to first explain what he/she is doing wrong in his/her attempt. That way you first teach the OP about his/her mistake and then in addition an alternative solution. That's called hunting two birds with a single shot. @jedwards provides a comprehensive answer below. In addition to that, you should also add explanations to one liner solutions, especially for readers who are beginners

Comment: @Bazingaa better? :)

Comment: I would remove the OP's original code form your answer.

Comment: @Bazingaa yeah it was supposed to be his modified code pasted over I noticed and fixed that accordingly, wanted to show him his code works if he took out the extra syntax he used

Answer (score 1):

Because student is a list, not the numerical index, you should use

```
for i in range(len(studentGrid)):
   antw.append(avg(studentGrid[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`studentgrades[student]` does not make sense, because `student` is a list of scores.  You can just use `student` (better name it `student_scores` or something).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop, `for student in studentgrades:` will set, on each iteration, `student` to be one of the sublists.

So for the first iteration, `student` will be the sublist `[95, 92, 86]`.

So the next line,

```
average = sum(studentgrades[student]) / len(studentgrades[student])
```

Will raise that error, as you're attempting to index (access) a list (`studentgrades`) by using another list (`student`).

One way to fix this would be to iterate over the `studentgrades` list (as you're doing) then use *that* list in your average calculation:

```
for student in studentgrades:
    average = sum(student) / len(student)
    antw.append(average)
```

To put that visually, that code would result in a first iteration that'd look like:

```
for student in studentgrades:
    average = sum([95, 92, 86]) / len([95, 92, 86])
    antw.append(average)
```

If you *really* wanted to index `studentgrades` every time, you might change your code to something like:

```
for index in range(len(studentgrades)):
    average = sum(studentgrades[index]) / len(studentgrades[index])
    antw.append(average)
```

But the first option of iterating over the sublists (instead of the output of a `range` generator) seems much better :)